# How does $\sqrt{S_1S_2S_3S_4}-\sqrt{(kS_1)(kS_2)(kS_3)(kS_4)}$ become $\sqrt{(S_1-kS_1)(S_2-kS_2)(S_3+kS_3)(S_4+kS_4)}$?

Tags: geometry, area

In the proof given in the *Forum Geometricorum* paper ["Highway from Heron to Brahmagupta" (PDF link via fau.edu)](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2012volume12/FG201215.pdf), Albrect Hess writes

$$\begin{align}
4A &= \sqrt{\left(S_1S_2S_3S_4\right)}-\sqrt{ \left({\lambda}S_1)({\lambda}S_2)({\lambda}S_3)({\lambda}S_4 \right)} \\
&= \sqrt {\left(S_1-{\lambda}S_1)(S_2-{\lambda}S_2)(S_3+{\lambda}S_3)(S_4+{\lambda}S_4 \right)} 
\end{align}$$
That step is the one I don't understand.

The triangles $XBC$ and $XDA$ in the given figure are similar and the similarity ratio is $\lambda$.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can factor out $\sqrt{S_1S_2S_3S_4}$ from all four square roots.

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: Hint: with $x:=S_1S_2S_3S_4$ you're asking why $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{\lambda^4x}=\sqrt{(1-\lambda^2)^2x}$.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you all.